# conversion between a pointer to function and another type [MISRA 2012 Rule 11.1, required] | pclint 9074

Tags: c, misra, pc-lint

I am using an array of function pointers as below to avoid a `switch` statement in the code.

```
void E_func1(void);
void E_func2(void);
void E_func3(void);

void (*pfGetVal[3])() = {
      E_func1,
      E_func2,
      E_func3
};
```

But while running misra (pclint), I am getting the error below:

> conversion between a pointer to function and another type [MISRA 2012
> Rule 11.1, required]

Do I need to use `typedef` ?

I tried as below but didn't work.

```
void (*pfGetVal[3])();  
pfGetVal[0] = E_func1;
pfGetVal[1] = E_func2;
pfGetVal[2] = E_func3;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An empty parameter list `void func ()` does *not* mean a function taking no parameters, but a function accepting *any* parameters. In C, the `()` form is obsolete style and should never be used.

Not to be confused with C++ where `void func ()` and `void func (void)` are identical.

Some compilers allow implicit conversions from `()` to `(void)` style function pointers, but they are strictly speaking different types and MISRA-C checkers are much more pedantic than mainstream compilers when it comes to type safety.

Fix this by declaring the function pointer list as `void (*pfGetVal[3])(void)`. Or better yet:

```
typedef void GetVal (void);

GetVal* const pfGetVal[3] = 
{
  E_func1,
  E_func2,
  E_func3
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper definition for `pfGetVal` is:

```
void (*pfGetVal[3])(void) = {
      E_func1,
      E_func2,
      E_func3
};
```

Unless you intend to modify this array during the execution of the program, you should define it as constant data:

```
void (* const pfGetVal[3])(void) = {
      E_func1,
      E_func2,
      E_func3
};
```